# Guice Module bind Object constructed with Injected Class

Tags: configuration, dependency-injection, guice

I'm new to Guice, so excuse me if this is a dumb question, but I'm finding it quite frustrating.

In my module I construct an object which is a member of a framework that I do not control. I then bind that instance so that I can access it later with injector.getInstance(FrameworkClass.class);

When I construct that object, I want to use one of my own objects which itself is annotated to be injected by constructor.

i.e.

```
public class MyClass { 
    OtherClass dependency;

    @Inject
    Public MyClass(OtherClass dependency) {
       ....
    }
}

public class AModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        MyClass frameworkDependency = ???
        FrameworkClass fc = new FrameworkClass(frameworkDependency);
        bind(FrameworkClass.class).toInstance(fc);
    }
}
```

In this example OtherClass is just a simple class with no annotations but a default empty constructor, so Guice should just new one up and provide it to MyClass constructor as far as I understand.

My question is How do I get access to a new instance of MyClass in my module so that I can provide it to the framework class?

Previously I had my own class injected via Field Injection, so it looked like this:

```
public class MyClass { 

    @Inject
    OtherClass dependency;      
}

public class AModule extends AbstractModule {

    protected void configure() {
        MyClass frameworkDependency = new MyClass();
        requestInjection(frameworkDependency);
        FrameworkClass fc = new FrameworkClass(frameworkDependency);
        bind(FrameworkClass.class).toInstance(fc);
    }
}
```

I would prefer to keep MyClass as constructor injected if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a `@Provides` method, as in your answer, every parameter will be resolved through the injector--including dependencies that use binding annotations, and including parameters of type `Provider<MyClass>` instead of just MyClass. Injecting `Provider`s is the best way to retrieve multiple instances of a dependency in one class.

```
@Provides FrameworkClass provideFrameworkClass(
    Dependency1 dep1, Provider<Dependency2> dep2Provider) {
  return new FrameworkClass(dep1, dep2Provider.get(), dep2Provider.get());
}
```

If all of your bindings can be found through Guice, you can more-or-less externally mark a constructor with `@Inject` by using a [`toConstructor` binding](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings). Note that the Guice docs actually prefer the `@Provides` technique over this technique, since getting Constructors reflectively is inherently more fragile than relying on your compiler. It may be a good option if you have a long parameter list, though.

Finally, if your @Provides method is big enough (or has complex-enough logic) to merit its own class, you can always create your own implementation of `Provider<FrameworkClass>`--complete with as much `@Inject`ion as you'd like--and implement the creation manually (bound through `bind(FrameworkClass.class).toProvider(FrameworkClassProvider.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer my own question (in its simplest form):

By moving the configuration of the Framework Object into a Provides method I can pass the MyClass object in as a parameter to the method and Guice handles in the instantiation of that parameter, ala:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
FrameworkClass provideFrameworkClass(MyClass dependency) {
    return new FrameworkClass(frameworkDependency);
}
```

But that begs the question what happens in the more complex case, what if my framework didn't take a single dependency, but n of them (say it's a dispatcher taking a bunch of actions), I can't just extend my provideFrameworkClass method to take n+ parameters?